# How to run the second function when the first function is complete and true

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 simple functions the first is to check the code if it's true or not. then I have the second one where some things happening. I want to run the second function only if the user enters the right code. I tried with Settimeout but after some second the second function runs without passing the test of the first.

Thank you for Help

Both are in the global scope

```
//Check The code To start the conversations
function CheckCode(msg) {
    const num = msg;
    
    //Check if The code is Valid 
    if(num == 333 ) {
        MessageEl.innerHTML = `<div>${msg} Code is Right, How are you Today!</div>`;
        return;
    }

     else {
        MessageEl.innerHTML = `<div>${msg} Code is Wrong, Please Speak The Right Code To talk to me</div>`;
        return;
     }

}


function TalkTheTalk(msg) {

    const talk = msg; 

    const greetings = ["I'm good", "I'm fine", "I'm Ok"];

     const result = greetings.find((greeting)=> {
         return greeting === talk;
        });

        if(result) {
            MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div> Im so happy to hear that! What can i do for you today ! </div>';
        }
        else {
            MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div>Sorry I didnt hear !Would you Repeat</div>';
            
        }    
    
}
```

Comment: You have to show the function calling code

Comment: Perhaps you should return a value from `CheckCode`, for example `true` or `false`.

Comment: what is stopping you to call the other function from if(num == 333) block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function fn1( rule ) {

  //The rules here
  if( rule == 'right' ) return true;
  return false;
  
}

function fn2() {
  if( fn1('right') ) {
     // fn2 codes here
     console.log('fn1, right');
  }
}

fn2();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but it didn't work, in my code, I don't have the string 'right' i compare it with a number,  if (fn1(1)) {........} it is good?

Comment: of course, what is the number you consider correct? You can equal it. This works too

Answer (score 2):

- Try Promise

```
var pro = function () { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      function CheckCode(msg) {
         const num = msg;
       if(num == 333 ) {
        MessageEl.innerHTML = `<div>${msg} Code is Right, How are you Today!</div>`;
        resolve(num)
        return;
      }
     else {
        MessageEl.innerHTML = `<div>${msg} Code is Wrong, Please Speak The Right Code To talk to me</div>`;
        return;
       }
     }
   })
}
pro().then(check_data => { 
  if(typeof check_data == "number") { 
     TalkTheTalk(check_data)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a bool to true when the correct code is entered and check it to issue the response you wish. Sorry the indentation is wrong.

```
//Check The code To start the conversations
boolean correct_code = 0;
function CheckCode(msg) {
    const num = msg;
    
    //Check if The code is Valid 
    if(num == 333 ) {
        MessageEl.innerHTML = `<div>${msg} Code is Right, How are you Today!</div>`;
        correct_code = true;
        
    }

     else {
        MessageEl.innerHTML = `<div>${msg} Code is Wrong, Please Speak The Right Code To talk to me</div>`;
        
     }

}


function TalkTheTalk(msg) {


    const talk = msg; 

    const greetings = ["I'm good", "I'm fine", "I'm Ok"];

     const result = greetings.find((greeting)=> {
         return greeting === talk;
        });

        if(result && corect_code == true) {
            MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div> Im so happy to hear that! What can i do for you today ! </div>';
        }
        else {
            MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div>Sorry I didnt hear !Would you Repeat</div>';
            
        }    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in various ways.
Here are some solutions:

1. Call function TalkTheTalk() inside function CheckCode() which is satisfying condition.
2. Use some Boolean flag to check condition is satisfied or not, and check that flag in 'if' condition of function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCode( msg ) {

  //check  the  message and  return appropriate boolean value
  if( msg == 'right' ) return true;
  return false;
  
}

function TalkTheTalk(msg) {

  if( checkCode(msg)  {
      //this executes when the  check code is satisfied
          console.log('fn1, right');
  }
}
```